# Android:Sending sms using internet

Tags: android, sms

I need to make an application in which i need to send smses through internet that is i want that no charges should be made for sending smses.I know how to send smses but can anyone please tell me how shall i accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to send SMS through internet is using SMS gateways.

Search on Google for "SMS Gateway"... you may still have to do some research in identifying the one that suits your needs.